# Switching bitrates of HLS stream in ios AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

I need to switch specific bitrate in HLS stream. To set the bitrate I am using the below property during initialisation .

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: streamUrl)
playerItem.preferredPeakBitRate = 240
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

But during the playback, if I am trying to set another bitrate using below code

```
self.playerController?.player?.currentItem?.preferredPeakBitRate = 1500
```

The stream is not switching to 720p.

Stream contains both the bitrates and works fine with whatever bitrate I provide during initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the preferredPeakBitRate is measured in bits per second and not resolution. After reviewing an Apple Developer video it seems that it's actually kilobits per second but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388541-preferredpeakbitrate) states otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** You can try this for preferredPeakBitRate

```
player?.currentItem?.preferredPeakBitRate = 700000 //for 240p
```

and for other bit rates
// 240p = 700000
// 360p = 1500000
// 480p = 2000000
// 720p = 4000000
// 1080p = 6000000
// 2k = 16000000
// 4k = 45000000